# If I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to a view, can I simply use touchesBegan et al whenever I'd like?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `handlePan:` method for when the user pans, but I want to know when they begin panning, so would it be best to use `touchesBegan`? Am I even able to? Does it conflict?

And how does `touchesMoved` differ from a UIPanGestureRecognizer anyway?

Comment: Apple pretty thoroughly explains all this in the WWDC videos on the gesture recognition system. I believe they're in the 2010 section.

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer is easier to use.  You can even animate the movement of a control.  And it's easier to tell the location of the control.  An alternative to it is touchesBegan and touchesMoved.  So it involves two methods.  Telling the location of the control is not so easy as the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gesture recognizer handler is called with different states. Make sure you look at the recognizer's state. This allows you to know when it starts, updates (called multiple times), and ends. There is no need to also implement the `touchesBegan` method to know when the pan starts.

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // handle start of gesture
    } else if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // handle updated position
    }
}
```

There are other states you may wish to handle. See the docs for `UIGestureRecognizer`.